# Having multiple databases in amazon neptune

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-neptune

In mysql we can create multiple databases and then we create different different tables in those database. e.g.

```
mysql> create database demo;
mysql> use demo;
mysql> create table test_demo (id int);
```

This allows us to create multiple tables under different different databases which provides virtual seggregation.

I am looking for similar stuff in amazon neptune. Is it possible to create different databases in amazon neptune and then to build the graph in those database which are independent from each other? If it is possible then how ?

Note: I don't want to create the separate cluster for my each graph hence above question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At present, Neptune is a single-tenant database service. This means that a single Neptune cluster can only host a single logical database.

If you're looking to use a single cluster to host data for multiple contexts/users, you would need to do this within the application and use different aspects of the data model to denote these different contexts.  For example, if you have a Person node label in your graph, you could use separate prefixes to denote which Person nodes relate to different users:  User1.Person, User2.Person, ..., UserX.Person.  Similar for edges and property keys.